# Select a portion of image in ImageView and retrieve the end points of selected rectangle

Tags: android, imageview

I need to drag and select a portion of an image set in an `ImageView` and retrieve the end points of the selected rectangle without causing any modifications (such as crop).

So far all I've been able to do is figure out the co-ordinates of the point where the user taps the screen.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //Simply displays a toast
        Utilities.displayToast(getApplicationContext(), "Touch coordinates : " +
                String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY())); 
        return true;
    }
});
```

But this is far from where I want to be. And I really haven't been able to find anything related on StackOverFlow/Google.

How can I implement it?

Comment: Do You need 'phone' coordinates or 'image' coordinates (mean, relative to real image size)?

Comment: @sandrstar : Relative to the real image size. Even the former would so since I can calculate the actual co-ordinates on the image using the measure with which it was scaled down.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way, that You can use (however, there's lot of possibilities to implement the same). It's based on creation of custom View for drawing and tracking of selection rectangle. Also, You can just apply the logic from `onTouch()` of custom view in yours `OnTouchListener()`.

Main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/up_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <com.example.TestApp.DragRectView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dragRect" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom view:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DragRectView extends View {

    private Paint mRectPaint;

    private int mStartX = 0;
    private int mStartY = 0;
    private int mEndX = 0;
    private int mEndY = 0;
    private boolean mDrawRect = false;
    private TextPaint mTextPaint = null;

    private OnUpCallback mCallback = null;

    public interface OnUpCallback {
        void onRectFinished(Rect rect);
    }

    public DragRectView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DragRectView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DragRectView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Sets callback for up
     *
     * @param callback {@link OnUpCallback}
     */
    public void setOnUpCallback(OnUpCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    /**
     * Inits internal data
     */
    private void init() {
        mRectPaint = new Paint();
        mRectPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
        mRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5); // TODO: should take from resources

        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(20);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

        // TODO: be aware of multi-touches
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mDrawRect = false;
                mStartX = (int) event.getX();
                mStartY = (int) event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final int x = (int) event.getX();
                final int y = (int) event.getY();

                if (!mDrawRect || Math.abs(x - mEndX) > 5 || Math.abs(y - mEndY) > 5) {
                    mEndX = x;
                    mEndY = y;
                    invalidate();
                }

                mDrawRect = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mCallback != null) {
                    mCallback.onRectFinished(new Rect(Math.min(mStartX, mEndX), Math.min(mStartY, mEndY),
                            Math.max(mEndX, mStartX), Math.max(mStartY, mEndY)));
                }
                invalidate();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mDrawRect) {
            canvas.drawRect(Math.min(mStartX, mEndX), Math.min(mStartY, mEndY),
                    Math.max(mEndX, mStartX), Math.max(mEndY, mStartY), mRectPaint);
            canvas.drawText("  (" + Math.abs(mStartX - mEndX) + ", " + Math.abs(mStartY - mEndY) + ")",
                    Math.max(mEndX, mStartX), Math.max(mEndY, mStartY), mTextPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity is simple:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final DragRectView view = (DragRectView) findViewById(R.id.dragRect);

        if (null != view) {
            view.setOnUpCallback(new DragRectView.OnUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onRectFinished(final Rect rect) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rect is (" + rect.left + ", " + rect.top + ", " + rect.right + ", " + rect.bottom + ")",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The output is like the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! :)
Is there any reason why you used a separate DragRectView on top of the ImageView? I also got it to work by extending the ImageView class containing the bitmap. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: I think, extending image view also fine. I've used separate view just to have functionality for drawing rectangle and tracking its coordinates in a separate entity.

Comment: What if I needed to calculate the image co-ordinates? What changes would have to be made?

Comment: Then You need to store image size, make correction for title and multiply by scale factor. I'll update the code to show it.

Comment: Yeah, that's right solution, I think. Sorry for delay (get some days off).

Comment: I'm late to the party on this one, but I get an error on "new DragRectView.OnUpCallback()" saying that it cannot create an instance of an interface...which makes total sense because it's defined as an interface, so I don't see how you're instantiating an interface here.

Comment: @gmaster please copy full source, there's no new interface, it's called anonymous class in java. You define class / interface same place there creating it.

Comment: @sandrstar I got it worked out but thanks!  I wound up just not using that part anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out your solution, it's pretty cool. Maybe I am wrong, but I think there is a typo in your Toast output:

```
mCallback.onRectFinished(new Rect(Math.min(mStartX, mEndX), Math.min(mStartY, mEndY),
                        Math.max(mEndX, mStartX), Math.max(mEndY, mStartX)));
```

must be:

```
mCallback.onRectFinished(new Rect(Math.min(mStartX, mEndX), Math.min(mStartY, mEndY),
                        Math.max(mEndX, mStartX), Math.max(mEndY, mStartY)));
```

otherwise the value of the bottom sometimes is calculated wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another way : https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

From the Doc:

> The Cropper is an image cropping tool. It provides a way to set an
>   image in XML and programmatically, and displays a resizable crop
>   window on top of the image. Calling the method getCroppedImage() will
>   then return the Bitmap marked by the crop window.
>
> Developers can customize the following attributes (both via XML and
>   programmatically):
>
> appearance of guidelines in the crop window whether the aspect ratio
>   is fixed or not aspect ratio (if the aspect ratio is fixed) image
>   resource A public method to rotate the image by a specified number of
>   degrees is also included. This can be used to provide the user with an
>   option to fix the image orientation should Android miscalculate the
>   intended orientation.
>
> Supported on API Level 7 and above.
>
> For more information, see the linked Github Wiki page.