# What is the best way to include cards images in my app?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, playing-cards

I'm writing an android app in java and in one of my activities I want to use a pack of 52 cards, and display a few of them randomly. Do I need to download and keep 52 images or is there other way of doing it?

I want to display different cards, randomly chosen. How can I get those images?

Comment: no, you don't need 52 images. Make one image with 52 cards and load the necessary card using x, y coordinates.

Comment: How can I load an image using coordinates? And how can I figure out the coordinates of each image? I found [this](http://www.jfitz.com/cards/classic-playing-cards.png)

Comment: I think you should refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765445/select-a-portion-of-image-in-imageview-and-retrieve-the-end-points-of-selected-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 ways of doing this:

1. Have a different image file for each card.
2. Have one large image of all cards and only draw a part of the image for each card.
3. Build the image of a card having several small images of the parts of a card.

If you're looking to save space on the device I would suggest number 3.

You would need images of the 4 suits, the faces(J,Q,K) and the blank card. The numbers and letters could simply be written in red and black.