# How to limit imagesize on crop in Android?

Tags: android, crop, resize-crop

I need to set max and min x,y size and rectangular crop area.

Is it possible?
If yes, how to Do It?

Crop method works well at normal usage but not customized, It Only Crop And I can't Limit crop size

How to set min and max crop size ? The method I am using is :

```
private void doCrop() {
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.crop_unavailable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // return
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        int y = 200;
        if(lastSelect == 1 || lastSelect == 2 || lastSelect == 3 || lastSelect == 4){
            y = (int) (200 * 0.5697329376854599);
        }
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", y);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0.5697329376854599);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res: list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.select_crop_app));
            builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    startActivityForResult(cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                }
            });

            builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null);
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765445/select-a-portion-of-image-in-imageview-and-retrieve-the-end-points-of-selected-r

Comment: no it doesn't, i an using crop app from device, and passing result to OnAcrivityResult, i need to Select ,Crop, And Save Cropped Image On SD-Card