# Select part of GLKViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, selection, drawrect

I'm try to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765445/select-a-portion-of-image-in-imageview-and-retrieve-the-end-points-of-selected-r) in my project. But I have some troubles with it. I plan to use UiPanGestureRecognizer for change size of rectangle. As I understand, I should be use UIVIew and custom drawRect method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an action for your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and use `translation`:

```
func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
    // Do your resizing here, e.g. from a 
    customView.frame.size.width = currentFrame.width + translation.x
    customView.frame.size.height = currentFrame.height + translation.y

    if gesture.state == .Ended {
        currentFrame = customView.frame
    }
}
```

Using this method, add a `CGRect` variable to store the `currentFrame`.

Comment: I do'nt understand. What is currentFrame ?

Comment: And, customView.frame.width is get-only property

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe Fixed, it should be `frame.size.width`. And `customView`is the view that you are resizing, `currentFrame` is just a property you should save the `customView`'s frame to after the gesture has ended so that the resizing will function properly.