# How to select the highlighted area from an image?

Tags: android, touch, android-canvas

The user can customize their given dress using different patterns or colors but only on highlighted area. For the given T-Shirt, the user can customise the sleeves, color and pockets. Whenever the user selects these areas, I need to highlight them with hyphenated points like the cut option. Then the user can replace the sleeves, color with some other patterns from the predefined images.

How can the above concept be done? How can we detect the exact touch position for the colors, sleeves and pocket areas alone. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Attached is one of the sample images which will be used in the project:

[image: Simply drawn over the color, sleeves and pocket area. User can customize those area only]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765445/select-a-portion-of-image-in-imageview-and-retrieve-the-end-points-of-selected-r

Comment: @sai: I have already seen the above link. That is square selection..But thanks for your link here i want the exact shape selection. If user touch on the sleeves area.. it should be automatically selected .